# Optimizing array overlap query using && operator

Tags: arrays, postgresql, performance, query-optimization

I have a relatively simple query that attempts to calculate the count of rows I'll have to deal with in a later operation. It looks like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM my_table AS t1
WHERE t1.array_of_ids && ARRAY[cast('1' as bigint)];
```

The tricky piece is that ARRAY[] portion is determined by the code that invokes the query so instead of having 1 element in this example it could have hundreds or thousands. This makes the query take a decent amount of time to run if a user is actively waiting for the calculation to complete.

Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong or any obvious improvement that could be made?
Thanks!

Edit:

There are not any indexes on the table. I tried to create one with

```
CREATE INDEX my_index on my_table(array_of_ids);
```

and it came back with

```
ERROR:  index row requires 8416 bytes, maximum size is 8191
```

I'm not very experienced here unfortunately. Maybe there is simply too many rows for an index to be useful?

I ran an explain on the query and the output essentially looks like:

```
QUERY PLAN |    Filter: ((array_of_ids && '{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ... n}'::bigint[])
```

so I guess it is automatically doing the ::bigint[]. I tried this as well and the query takes the same time to execute which I guess makes sense.

I realize I'm only pasting a portion of the response to the `explain (analyze, buffers, format text)` but I'm doing this in psql and my system often runs out of memory. There are tons of --- in the output, I am not sure if there is a way to not have psql do that.

The plan looks pretty simple so is this basically saying there is no way to optimize this? I have two huge arrays and it just takes time to determine an overlap? Not sure if there is a JOIN solution here, I tried to unnest and do a JOIN on equivalent entries but the query never returned so I'm not sure if I got it wrong or if it is just a far slower approach.

Comment: [Edit] the question and add the `CREATE` statements of the table and any indexes on it. [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) the query and post the results. It might also help if you tagged the version of Postgres you use.

Comment: If it was a regular integer not a `bigint` you could use the [intarray extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html) to create an index on the `array_of_ids` column

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: Assuming you do have an index on `array_of_ids`: does using `ARRAY[1]::bigint[]` change anything?